# pdflatex compilation error in CI job, but not in interactive shell

Tags: pdftex, docker

I get an error while compiling my document inside a Ubuntu 22.04 docker container during a Gitlab CI job:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file tcrm1000): Font tcrm1000 at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The strangest thing is that if I start the container manually and then compile the document then I get no error. I'd need more insights about what can generate the above error (e.g. environment variables?) in order to troubleshoot it.

Edit: inspecting the logs for the failed compilation more carefully I found this:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 tcrm1000
mktexpk: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexdir ./.texlive2021/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec failed.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

For the successful manual execution instead I get:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 tcrm1000
mktexpk: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1+0/600; nonstopmode; input tcrm1000
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)
. . .
```

It seems that this could be the main error, but I don't understand why it happens only for CI.

Comment: text companion fonts `texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/tcrm.mf`  but there should be map files installed such that the type1 version is used rather than the 600dpi pk files

Comment: I don't fully understand the comment (I'm not a LaTeX expert at all), but is it relevant for the fact that using the very same container the manual compilation works while the one triggered by the CI doesn't?

Comment: you appear to have two systems installed, one of your logs shows texlive 2022 the other texlive 2021, which is a bit odd as you are using the debian system installed texlive in /usr/bin and /usr/share/texlive

Comment: That's strange, I just installed the texlive texlive-font-utils ghostscript packages from the official repositories on the vanilla Ubuntu 22.04 image from dockrhub... Guess I have to clarify this.

Comment: Well, I don't understand: pdflatex version says "pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)"; the executable is provided by the "texlive-latex-extra" package, whose installed version is "2021.20220204-1". So pdflatex seems to be the 2022 version, albeit the package that provides looks like a rebuild of the 2021 version done in 2022 (perhaps?).

Comment: On some systems (such as mine, which is an Android tablet that runs jailed Linux via an app), the texlive executables must come from the app provided. They cannot come from TUG, because of the fake root. But macros can (and do) come from the TeXLive installer, with modified paths. Although something is supposed to trap problems when the executable year is not the same as the macro installer year, perhaps that is not always trapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: the shell spawned by the CI is missing the definition of the HOME environment variable. This leads to a bad expansion of ~ in the TEXMFVAR defined in texmf.cnf (which in my system is ~/.texlive2021/texmf-var), and in turn to a bad name for the folder that the mktexdir script tries to create. All of this didn't happen for the manual compilation since I was doing that in an interactive shell inside the same container, and for this shell HOME was properly defined.

I was able to fix by adding this line:

```
- export HOME=/root
```

to the CI script before the call to pdflatex.

Comment: If you can accept your own answer, do so. It is also of value to others who may have a similar problem

Comment: In 16 hours I will be able to do so ;-)